# Remote desktop connection failed Windows Azure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, azure

I have a trial account in Windows Azure, I installed a SharePoint server 2013 VM. When I try to connect to it the connection failed

1. The 3389 port is enabled in my VM (I also added  80 and 443 ports) but still failed
2. I'm using the school network (which have a proxy and some restrictions)

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the network, when I tried to connect using the house network it worked

So the solution for this problem is to contact the network administrator.

Edit :

I returned to give my feedback  (hope that help someone )

I modified the Remote Desktop Public port from  3389  to  443 (https ) and it worked